# "Художник, что рисует дождь..." "Что" или "который"?

Tags: предлоги

**"Меня ты скоро позабудешь, художник, что рисует дождь..."**

Является ли употребление союзного слова "что" ошибочным в данном тексте?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё правильно: "Меня ты скоро позабудешь, художник, что (=который) рисует дождь..."

Союзное слово КОТОРЫЙ часто заменяется в зависимости от смысла на союзные слова ЧТО, ГДЕ, КОГДА, ОТКУДА, например: Сегодня это уже не тот город, что был вчера, и завтра будет не тот, что сегодня (В. Г. Распутин).

Comment: Спасибо, Vera !

Comment: Оно, конечно, так. Заменяется. Часто. Вопрос, что об этом думает грамматика. У Распутина на "что" заменено не "который", а "какой". Вот тут сомнений нет. Это узаконенная замена. А вот в отношении "который", как-то немного просторечием отдает.

Comment: Это Ваше собственное мнение (вот тут сомнений нет, это узаконенная замена)? Вообще-то в грамматике сказано вот что: который, какой и что - это универсальные союзные слова, но "какой" замещает не только название предмета, но и его качественный признак, выполняя качественно-типизирующую функцию. По поводу "что" сказано, что союзное слово должно быть подлежащим или дополнением. Разговорно-просторечное: " Это вы про каких Туркиных Это про тех, что  (у которых) дочка играет на фортепьянах ?"