# Какой, который, что

Tags: грамматика

Какие существуют правила употребления слов *который*, *какой* и *что*? Какая разница между словами *который* и *что*?

Comment: Подобные вопросы: “Художник, что рисует дождь…” “Что” или “который”? (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417053/%d0%a5%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9)

Comment: Можно ли так писать: “единственный, что …”? (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437279/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be)

Answer (score 5):

У Розенталя (в учебнике для вузов "Современный русский язык") есть такие сведения по применению союзных слов ***который, какой, что*** в СПП с придаточными определительными.

Местоимение **КОТОРЫЙ** является универсальным и имеет чисто определительное значение, местоимение  **КАКОЙ** вносит оттенок сравнения или уподобления, местоимение **ЧТО** заменяет  местоимение КОТОРЫЙ, но при этом имеет определенные особенности.

Местоимение ЧТО придает речи эмоциональность, например: Виктор Гюго ворвался в классический и скучноватый век, как ураганный ветер, как вихрь, **что несет потоки дождя**, листья...

В  придаточном предложении ЧТО выполняет роль подлежащего или прямого дополнения (И.п. и В.п.). Также ЧТО не согласуется с определяемым существительным (в главном предложении) в роде и числе (это надо учитывать при построении предложения).

Посмотрим. как это выглядит **на примерах.**

1) **КОТОРЫЙ** (**распространительное** значение, нельзя использовать указательное слово): Потом подул сильный ветер, который (=он) становился холоднее с каждым порывом.

2) **КОТОРЫЙ** (**выделительное** значение из ряда однородных предметов): Из их вздохов рождается **тот** ветер, **который** превращается в бури.

3) **КАКОЙ** (**качественное** значение, выделение по признаку): Дул **такой** легкий и сладостный ветер, **какой** только может дуть в сентябре, и участковый подставлял ему лицо.

4) **ЧТО**  (заменяет КОТОРЫЙ в разных значениях):

Устал **тот** ветер, **что** листал страницы мировой истории.

Как ветер, **что** к ним летел с небес, Умытый студеной звездой...

Еще и ветер, **что** относил в ту сторону взволнованные дымки цигарок, долетал туда за каких-нибудь три счета и вот уже кудрявил надворные ветлы...

Дай Бог, чтобы сохранились, особенно в наши дни, **такие** люди, **что** ставят во главу угла не чистый заработок, а интересы дела...

Примечание.

Хотя ЧТО (в паре *такой ― что*) заменяет одушевленный предмет (что не очень естественно), такие предложения встречаются в тексте.  И есть еще один недостаток ― неразличение союзного слова ЧТО и союза ЧТО со значением следствия, например : Дул **такой** пронзительный ветер, **что** буквально сносил нас с ног (значение следствия).