# Правильно ли использовать "что" в значении "который"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, семантика

> Потрепала по голове парня с каштановыми волосами, ***что*** сидел перед ними.

Корректно ли в данном случае использовать "что", а не "который"?

Comment: Можно, можно даже "кто" сказать. Есть небольшая разница в том, какой смысловой акцент будет приобретать фраза. Что - более общий вопрос, Который - более частный, Кто - личный. Кто - когда речь идет об людях, личностях. Который - это один из, представитель вида, индивидуальность, индивидуум, субъект. Что - это просто о предметах неодушевленных, объектах, то есть в данном случае есть акцент на том что "парень" это тело парня, парень - что, незнакомый парень. Кто - когда знаешь о ком говоришь, который, когда выделяешь кого-то из группы подобных.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417053/%d0%a5%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9 Повтор вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Раз повтор и удалят, то на примере:

Потрепала по голове парня с каштановыми волосами, что сидел перед ними. Парень сначала сморщился, а потом замахнулся на Вальку.

..Потрепала по голове парня с каштановыми волосами, кто сидел перед ними.

-Василий, а я тебя сразу узнала! - бойко протараторила Валька.

Затем, она заметила ватагу переминающихся с ноги на ногу мальчишек. Валя, прямо на ходу, потрепала по голове парня с каштановыми волосами, который сидел перед ними.